# Как поставить ударение в названии кафе

Tags: орфоэпия

Кафе называется "Мост". Как правильно сказать: мы были в мостЕ или в мОсте?
2. "Холст", мы были в хОлсте или в холстЕ?

Пожалуйста, обоснуйте ответ.

P.S. О том, что можно сказать, что мы были в кафе "Мост", я в курсе.)

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря: мост - о мОсте и о мостЕ (два варианта), холст - о холстЕ (один вариант).

Мы были в "МОсте" и в "МостЕ", первый вариант, может быть, предпочтительнее, так как не искажает название при чередовании О/А.

Мы были в в "ХолстЕ".